# How to get location permission in php or Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, geolocation, location, geo

I want to check the browsers location permission in a laravel middleware. is there any php or laravel function or method to check or get the location permission of users browser?

Comment: no, location permissions are handled on client-side(from the browser), if you want to use them in middleware, then you need to pass them to the backend by saving them to a cookie or send them with the request.

Comment: You can't get location by backend, check this link to get current location by javascript
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

and make two hidden fields longitude and latitude and change value by javascript